# How would one apply production level code to a coding challenge take home interview in python?

Tags: python, production

Say the question is to make a function that finds the highest integer in a list, and I need a helper function.

Could I just have a file `highest_int.py`, that will work as a module which contains the two functions? And then maybe `test_highest_int.py` for a test suite with edge cases?

Not sure what else would would be required to have for an interview take home question with "production level code" requirement, perhaps some documentation rather than just comments in the module?

Comment: pep8 compliant, doc strings, unit test, decent variable names... and a good implementation.

Comment: any quick breakdown of pep8 compliant, as well as doc strings? I feel like a good implementation, with unit tests and decent variable names is a prerequisite for university based code, let alone production code.

Comment: Should I be using sphinx or wheels?

Comment: That's interesting. An installable program (setup.py / distutils) documentation with sphinx, maybe even all bundled up in a git or mercurial repository. That would be cool.